# D3 v4 - Accessing selection array and find corresponding element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to get a constraint relaxing to work for my piechart.
It is based on this example https://jsfiddle.net/thudfactor/HdwTH/ but the relaxing method used seems not to work with v4 any more.
The concrete problem is how they access the selection group array directly:

```
textLabels = labelGroups.append("text").attr( ... );

if(again) {
        labelElements = textLabels[0];     <------------- here
        textLines.attr("y2",function(d,i) {
            labelForLine = d3.select(labelElements[i]);
            return labelForLine.attr("y");
        });
        setTimeout(relax,20)
    }
```

Has it changed with D3 v4.x how you access a selections group array?
How would you go about it now?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In D3 4.0, selections are not arrays anymore. According to the API:

> Selections no longer subclass Array using prototype chain injection; they are now plain objects, improving performance.

So, if you `console.log(textLabels)`, you're gonna see something like this:

```
{_groups: Array[1], _parents: Array[1]}
```

Depending on exactly what are you selecting. From there, you can access your array using `textLabels._groups`, for instance.

For having an array, you have to use `selection.nodes()`, which, according to the API:

> Returns an array of all (non-null) elements in this selection.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gerardo, that gave me the right clue to make it work!
`selection.nodes()` does the trick and now with v4 returns an array of the nodes included in the selection.

Comment: @TommyF I wish I could upvote this a hundred times. I was looking everywhere for the last 40 minutes.