# getBBox of selection with D3 v4

Tags: d3.js

I tried using [d3.legend.js](http://bl.ocks.org/ZJONSSON/3918369) with d3 v4 but ran into a problem. So I ported index.html to use d3 v4 to see if the problem was in my code or in d3.legend.js. See [my gist](https://gist.github.com/louking/6491d18c9cef56011971be76a85cde8e) ([running version](http://bl.ocks.org/louking/6491d18c9cef56011971be76a85cde8e)) - the problem is at line 47 of d3.legend.js `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

I'm not that familiar with d3 (or the changes from v3) to understand how to fix this error -- any ideas?

UPDATE 1: This appears to have something to do with the way d3 selections have changed, per [the release notes](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection).

But still not sure how to access the getBBox() method from the li Selection.

UPDATE 2: `li.node().getBBox()` works if `li` is non-null. For some reason code like

```
var li = g.selectAll(".legend-items")
             .data(["g"])
           .enter()
             .append("g")
             .attr("class", "legend-items")
```

leaves `li` as null if the class already exists.

I was forced to use the (somewhat inelegant)

```
var licreate = g.selectAll(".legend-items")
        .data(["g"])
      .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend-items");
var li = g.selectAll(".legend-items");
```

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702831/d3-v4-accessing-selection-array-and-find-corresponding-element/38703314#38703314

Comment: Thanks. Please see UPDATE 2. I had tried node() but I was confused by the null value of li the second time through my code. I worked around it as described.

Comment: I still don't see an 'answer' to this question. It's 2018 and v4 has been out for some time. I'll post this issue to the npm maintainer's actual Github project.

Answer (score 5):

This question was posted in the first days of D3 v4, and it uses a D3 plugin from 2012, way before v4 (and actually before v3 as well).

The necessary changes here are two:

1. In D3 v4 selections are not arrays, but objects instead. Therefore, using `[0][0]` won't work here. It should use `node()` instead:

   ```
   var lbbox = li.node().getBBox()
   ```
2. In D3 v4 the "enter" selection doesn't magically change the "update" selection anymore. Therefore, it should be:

   ```
   lb = lb.enter().append("rect").classed("legend-box",true).merge(lb);
   li = li.enter().append("g").classed("legend-items",true).merge(li);
   ```

   Also, as I can't see an update situation for the "update" selection, I suggest that you use a simple "enter" selection here.

Here is the updated bl.ocks: http://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/raw/ca06385c40afa5414830b3d3d449cbe5/efeeed6ffc42051f433cfcb54c462acfd0daebb5/